# Generate C++ code based on XML/JSON definition?

Tags: c++, eclipse, code-generation, codegen

I'm writing some small service application (no UI) for an embedded system, in C++. Part of the concept includes independent blocks which define program logic and I want to make them configurable. In other words, I would like to split logic in small modules, each consists of

-> cpp/hpp file with particular logic, derived from basic module class
-> manifest (JSON/XML) which describes module parameter

Now I want to generate the "glue code" based on manifests (starting as simple as which modules to start which not). I can imagine that I need a perl/python script which would process manifest and generate .cpp file based on template.

But the challenge is how to integrate it into build process? I'm currently using Eclipse CDT but I may move to pure gcc/make generation.
The generation script must obviously run as first in build process.

Comment: You can add any build steps you like with the eclipse build system.

Comment: _"but I may move to pure gcc/make generation."_ The same is true for a plain `make` based build system of course.